# Wrap up selected text in PhpStorm by hotkey?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Well, a simple question: I need to wrap the selected text in some kind of text construction when I press an arbitrary combination of keys. For example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Code > Surround with..** feature (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) to surround a selected tag with another tag/Emmet abbreviation or [surround live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.1/using-live-templates.html#live_templates_types)

To comment out the selection, just hit `Ctrl+/` or `Ctrl+Shift+/` (**Code | Comment with line comment** or **Comment with block comment**)